# crossdomain problems: swf frame script not calling when swf loading from sub-domain

Tags: actionscript-3, flash

I have character.swf (published with flash CS6) that contains character animations with some simple frame scripts in child movieClips(gotoAndPlay(), stop() etc) and game.swf - main programm that loads character.swf for using it in game.

If game and character are in the same domain (http://client.mygame.com) then frame scripts in character.swf are working fine. But if I put character to different domain (http://resources.mygame.com) then frame scripts are not working. Possible not envoked at all.

crossdomain.xml is correct and all swf-s contain allow domain code such as :

```
Security.allowDomain("*");
Security.allowInsecureDomain("*");
```

Is there any ideas why it happens?

[upd]  I found some pattern in the behavior of scripts working. It seems they are not working only if I create an instance of character by ApplicationDomain.getDefinition(className). If I use loaded content directly, scripts are working

Answer (score 0):

First of all - any Security Error would've been traced to the output - can you confirm that you don't see any errors in the output? Have you set `checkPolicyFile` when loading character.swf with Loader? Check if you have this: [LoaderContext - checkPolicyFile](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/system/LoaderContext.html#checkPolicyFile)

Comment: I run aplication in debug flash player and there is no exceptions. And I sets checkPolicyFile=true on loading. But I found some pattern in the behavior of scripts working. It seems they are not working only if  I create an instance of character by ApplicationDomain.getDefinition(className). If I use loaded content directly, scripts are working.